# Special character in string to be stored in database using MVC model

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, culture

I need to store a string in a table and it will be in the Vietnamese language (vowels are special, i.e. á, à, ả, etc)

```
public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
```

In SQL Sever, the datatype **name** column is `nvarchar(50)`.

Comment: And what problem do you face ?, a nvarchar column shouldn't have trouble storing vietnamese strings.

Comment: If you have an issue we'll need to see your MVC code.